# Customize serialization of property during XML serialization when attribute is present

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have a requirement to wrap certain property values in a CDATA tag during XML serialization.

I want to control this by adding a custom attribute to those properties that require the CDATA tag (let's call it "CDATASection" or something).

Is there a way to accomplish this without writing a whole new XML serializer?